# I provide complete path in href tag still it says resource not available. why?

Tags: java, servlets, jsp-tags

[image]

I give complete from web-Inf path here I don't know why its not working when i click contact it give me error 400  The requested resource () is not available.

Comment: Post code instead of a screenshot, please. This is hard to read and even harder to duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

Use below line if you want to add another jsp in your current jsp.

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/Jsp/contact.jsp"%>
```

Links:[JSP iNclude Directive](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/include_directive.htm)

Comment: but i need to add that in href tag so first i need to include this and then  i should add  it in href ?

Comment: why do you need to add a uri to a jsp in href attribute of an anchor tag?